# How to handle a POST request in lighttpd + mod_magnet with lua?

Tags: lua, lighttpd

I've figured out how to handle a GET request and get all query parameters but couldn't see how to get the JSON body of a POST request. And I went through all the keys of the lighty object but couldn't figure out how where the JSON body is stored. Is there a way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd mod_magnet can manipulate the request from the request headers and can short-circuit a response, but the lighttpd hooks from which mod_magnet runs are before the request handler; mod_magnet does not have access to the request body, which may not have been received yet, since the request body is pulled in the request handler.

If you need access to the request body, then your code must run as a request handler.  You can run your lua as a CGI script (mod_cgi) or some other backend, e.g. FastCGI (mod_fastcgi), SCGI (mod_scgi), HTTP (mod_proxy), etc.

Comment: lighttpd 1.4.65 (released Jun 2022) and later provides API methods that can be used to collect the request body in full (buffered to disk) and then to run the lua script.